# Flutter constructor arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw the following code in a [Flutter tutorial](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/fluttertimertutorial) .

```
@immutable
abstract class TimerState extends Equatable {
  final int duration;

  TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props));
}
```

I cannot understand the code in the constructor. Can somebody please explain what is happening here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constructor has 2 positional parameters:
1st is `this.duration`, which will initialise `final int duration` field. `this.something` in constructor means that it will initialise the field with name `something` of created instance.
2nd parameter is optional positional, because it is listed in square brackets. It is a `List` without type parameter, so this list can contain mix of any objects. If value of this list is not set then default value of empty list is used (`= const []`). `const` keyword here is used because by dart rules default parameters of constructors must be compile-time constants.

So calls `TimerState(10)` and `TimerState(10, [])` will return equal results.

Next part is call to constructor of parent class `Equatable`. This class belongs to [`equatable package`](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable). This class is made to simplify overriding `operator ==` by removing boilerplate code. Instead of describing each field in comparison, it puts values of all fields to one list and compares this list.
Call looks like `: super([duration]..addAll(props))`.
Here `[duration]` means creation of `List` containing `duration`.
`..addAll(props)` takes created list with duration, adds everything from `props` list passed in `TimerState` constructor, and returns this new list with duration and props inside. It is done only to simplify comparison of `TimerState` objects for equality.

So by calling `TimerState(10, [prop1, prop2, prop3])` you will create a `TimerState` with duration set to 10, which will call `Equatable` constructor with parameter `[10, prop1, prop2, prop3]`

I hope I did not confuse you even more :)
I think usage of `Equatable` in this example is overkill, because there is only one actual property and `props` in `TimerState` are never used

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It all makes sense once I read your answer except for one thing; the usage of .. (cascade) operator here. I thought it would be used to do multiple operations on the same object like list.add(x)..add(y). Here add(x) returns void, so .. needs to be used. But in the code above, [duration]..addAll(props) is used. Why does [duration].addAll(props) throw an error? Doesn't [duration] return a List object so that we can call the addAll method directly ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim addAll returns void too, so cascade operator is required to return a  list

Comment: I have also seen const <dynamic>[]. Is that the same thing as const []?

Answer (score 0):

This might also be better written these days using the spread operator:

```
super([duration]..addAll(props))
```

becomes

```
super([duration,...props])
```

At least if I'm understanding the syntax properly.  If not, someone will whack me with the appropriate ruler. :)